# How to call function from generic function without knowing the type?

Tags: kotlin, generics, functional-programming

Is there a way to do the following?:

```kotlin
class Someotherthing
class SomeotherthingDTO

class Something
class SomethingDTO

fun convert(entity: Someotherthing): SomeotherthingDTO = SomeotherthingDTO()
fun convert(entity: Something): SomethingDTO = SomethingDTO()

fun <T, D> generic(entity: T): D {
    // TODO: check here if there is convert() that accepts type T?! somehow? reflection? reification? or it will be possible only in the future by using typeclasses (KEEP-87)?
    return convert(entity)
}

fun main() {
    val x: SomethingDTO = convert(Something())
    println(x.toString())
}
```

Currently, the result is: none of the following can be called with the arguments supplied...

Comment: It is not possible to do this automatically like you're describing. Even with a reified type, you would have to use when statements to check the type and manually select the appropriate function.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. Would you see a possible workaround? Using something completely different? I just wanted to implement some methods outside of the classes themselves. Including some interface would work, but then I would need to implement the interface IN the class, not outside. Do you see any other way? Or is the KEEP-87 (typeclasses) the only way to do this?

Comment: Do extension functions match your needs?

Comment: They would, if I could define a generic function which depends not on an interface, but more like "is this extension function defined for that type?" (Because you cannot mark class with an interface (which you need in generic function above) and implement that interface in an extension function...)

Comment: Haskell can do it via typeclasses, but it's nteresting that some other compiled strongly typed static languages can do it. Crystal can do it - no questions asked, Nim can do it too - no questions asked. It's a pity Kotlin cannot do it in any way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need multiple receviers for this to work (KEEP-87). With those you'll be able to "find" the receivers properly.

Until then what I usually do is to put `Converter`s in a `ConverterRegistry` to do the conversion like this:

```
interface Converter<A, B> {
    val fromClass: KClass<A>
    val toClass: KClass<B>

    fun convert(from: A): B

    fun convertBack(from: B): A
}

interface ConverterRegistry {
    fun <A, B> tryConvert(from: KClass<A>, to: KClass<B>): B?
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's definitely one way to work around it. But then I would need to have all these registries for all the different stuff... and manage registration to it... Which is not very elegant. Spring's autowire can do this generic type automatically too, e.g. `val service: Converter<Something, SomethingDTO>` will autowire `@Component` impl with these types automatically. But I don't want to use classes for this, because these won't have access to `this` - to the original entity. (E.g. calling one converter from another would need access to the registry.)

Comment: This is what multiple receivers will solve (among others). Right now I can't imagine a simpler/better solution for your problem.

Comment: I'll mark it as an answer - because you are right in that currently better solution doesn't exist.